# Error executing stored procedure with uniqueidentifier input parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, uniqueidentifier

When I execute the stored procedure that has the first input parameter of type `uniqueidentifier` which is the primary key column in a table that inserts the values into, it is throwing the below error. I couldn't find whats wrong with this input or stored procedure.

```
EXEC    @return_value = DbInsert
        @id =   EX642793-385D-604F-BE81-0000CD376836,
        @name= N'000001_067_0xed642993385d604fbe810000cd376836.tif',
        @image = 0x49492A00080000001300FE00040001000000020000000001040001000000C50900000101040001000000E90D0000020103000

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

My stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DbInsert
    @id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    @name VARCHAR(255),
    @image IMAGE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO TbImage (Id, Name, Image )
    VALUES (@id, @name, @image)
END
```

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
>   Incorrect syntax near '-'.

**Update**

I tried to right click the stored procedure and execute, and it didn't ask me for quote and all, but the query I wrote above is what it shown as error. When I try with quote, it throw below error

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 1, Procedure DbInsert, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 2]
>   Error converting data type varchar to uniqueidentifier. (1 row(s) affected)

**Update again**

Using valid `Uniqueidentifier` by changing some numbers myself, however replaced X with some other char...still no luck.

```
EM662993-385D-604F-BE81-0000CD376838
```

Comment: @DaleBurrell: It automatically gave me to input values in the right click and execute proc. Do I still need to manually put the quote?  I don't think so? And I have even put quote, it didn't help

Comment: Msg 8114, Level 16, State 1, Procedure DbInsert, Line 0 [Batch Start Line 2]
Error converting data type varchar to uniqueidentifier.

(1 row(s) affected)

Comment: @DaleBurrell: No luck mate, it throws the other error, however it also says one row affected, conflicting?

Comment: How did you come by that invalid guid anyway?

Comment: @DaleBurrell: I didn't know X is invalid, guess my pretty bad luck, I put X as a test only in that spot hehe.... lol I have bad programming luck as said in my astrology. Computers and me never go well even though I do better outputs lol

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 issues with your code:

1. You need to single quote uniqueidentifiers e.g. `'DE5AA552-0601-453C-AF21-9B285FA4E920'`.
2. A guid/uniqueidentifier must contain only valid hexidecimal characters, and `X` is not a valid hexidecimal character and is therefore not valid within a uniqueidentifier so `'EX642793-385D-604F-BE81-0000CD376836'` is not valid but `'EA642793-385D-604F-BE81-0000CD376836'` is. You can use http://guid.us/Test/GUID to verify and generate guids.

Comment: The 'X' is definitely the cause of 'Error converting data type varchar to uniqueidentifier'. Good spot +1

Comment: @Dale, I couldn't get that fixed. It is definitely not a problem with quotes, coz, if it is one, then Microsoft should redesign their Management studio to have this included automaticaly like it does for Varchar and char.

Comment: You see other columns, they are varchar and char, so MS automatically represented those in the single quote. But not for unique identifier.

Comment: It's not helping me, I could see no data inserted when I did select query, as it throws error saying unable to convert varchar to uniqueidentifier

Comment: Are you now using a valid guid? i.e. one without an `x`? If so please update your question.

Comment: EM662993-385D-604F-BE81-0000CD376838

Comment: `M` is not more valid than `X` - get yourself a working guid! You have to follow the the rules.

Comment: @DaleBurrell: I see, I just randomly change chars and numbers lol...but ensure I replacer char with char and number with number :D let me try your suggestion and let you know

Comment: @DaleBurrell: :p your valuable suggestion worked. Thank you so much :) However, I am still afraid why the heck Microsoft Management Studio of SQL don't  put quote for us when I just right click exec proc, it shows a dialog where I input values. It then brings this query window I posted above and there I don't see quote only for "Uniqueidentifier". But for char and varchar it does brings quote automatically. Why the heck is that? Or its my Studio setting?

Comment: @Learner - no idea - I never use that feature myself.